# Seahorse/gnupg: encryption not working properly in 14.10

Tags: encryption, 14.10, gnupg

I installed both 32bit and 64bit Utopic Unicorn on 2 PCs.
As I usually do, I copied the .gnupg folder into the /home directory and installed seahorse-nautilus. Now I can decrypt my old files as usual through the GUI (double-click and password), but I cannot encrypt any file anymore (right-click, encrypt, choice of the key to use). Easily, nothing happens.
Through the command line I can still encrypt/decrypt, everything works, so I know the keys are not "broken".
Is there anybody that can help me to fix this kind-of-bug?

Comment: Is it or is not a bug?  If it is you need to file a bug report respectfully at Bugzilla.org

Comment: Sorry, don't know if consider it a bug or not. In my opinion a bug is something that never works, but I can be wrong...Just wanted to know (and understand) if something can be done to solve this misfunctioning and make the process easier in a couple of mouse clicks.